# Check if paramiko ssh connection is still alive

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Is there a way to check if a `paramiko` SSH connection is still alive?

```
In [1]: import paramiko

In [2]: ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() 

In [3]: ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

In [4]: ssh.connect(hostname)
```

I want to mimic something like this (which doesn't currently exist)

```
In [5]: ssh.isalive()
True
```

Comment: whats wrong with `isalive` ?

Comment: Just edited to clarify that `isalive` doesn't actually exist.  It's the behavior that I want.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
 if ssh.get_transport() is not None:
     ssh.get_transport().is_active()
```

should do it .... assuming I read the [docs](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.is_active) right.

Comment: Great!  Any thoughts on `SFTPClient`?

Comment: Looks like you also need to check that `ssh.get_transport() is not None`

Answer (score 28):

I had observed `is_active()` returning false positives.

I would recommend using this piece:

```
  # use the code below if is_active() returns True
  try:
      transport = client.get_transport()
      transport.send_ignore()
  except EOFError, e:
      # connection is closed
```

Comment: This is the right answer. You can get a True response from `client.get_transport().is_active()` followed by a connection error from `client.exec_command`.

Answer (score 6):

For me the above answer doesn't work so I've done it by sending an **exec_command()** with a timeout :

```
self.ssh.exec_command('ls', timeout=5)
```

for exemple the full method will be like :

```
def check_connection(self):
    """
    This will check if the connection is still availlable.

    Return (bool) : True if it's still alive, False otherwise.
    """
    try:
        self.ssh.exec_command('ls', timeout=5)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print "Connection lost : %s" %e
        return False
```

and I call it every 5 or so seconds.

Comment: transport.is_active() / transport.is_alive() / transport.isAlive() wasn't working for me, taking waaaaay to much time to detect that the connection was lost and sometime never detect it (while the other computer was even powered off)

Comment: is_alive and is_active didn't work for me, they return true even when I disconnect the network, sending a command and having it fails is a more reliable way.

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues at the moment to download a file after 5 minutes or less of inactivity ( the exception that I was getting was `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException`), the way I handled a possible fix was the following:

```py
class ...:

def connect(self) -> paramiko.SFTPClient:
        """
        Important information to take into consideration:
        - with .ppk files, the following exception is being raised.
        paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: not a valid RSA private key file

        - a possible fix is to convert .ppk file to .pem file
        brew install putty
        puttygen <filename>.ppk -O private-openssh -o <filename>.pem

        - then the content of the .pem file should be updated in GCP secret manager.
        """

        transport = paramiko.Transport(self.hostname, int(self.port))
        params: Dict[str, Any] = {
            "username": self.username,
        }
        if self.password:
            params.update(
                {
                    "password": self.password,
                }
            )

        if self.certificate:
            private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(open(self.certificate))
            params.update(
                {
                    "pkey": private_key,
                }
            )

        transport.connect(**params)
        conn = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
        if conn:
            if required_directory := self.directory:
                conn.chdir(required_directory)
            return conn
        raise SFTPClientException(f"Unable to connect to sftp {self.hostname}")


def reconnect(self) -> None:
        """
        Start a new connection to sftp host
        """
        self.client = self.connect()

def download_file(self, path_file: str) -> str:
        """
        Download a file from a specific path.
        """
        from os import path

        local_destination: str = f"/tmp/{uuid4()}_{path.basename(path_file)}"
        try:
            self.client.get(path_file, local_destination)
        except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException:
            self.reconnect()
            self.client.get(path_file, local_destination)

        return local_destination
```

I really hope the shared code helps anybody who is facing a similar incident.