# Paramiko SFTPClient.get fails with "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" referring to the remote file path

Tags: python, linux, networking, ssh, sftp

I am trying to use Paramiko to get a log file from my Raspberry Pi:

```
import paramiko
paramiko.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log")

# Open a transport
host, port = RECV_IP_ADDRESS, 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))

# Auth
username, password = "pi", "raspberry"
transport.connect(None, username, password)
# Go!
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
# Download
filepath = "/"
localpath = "/home/pi/Code/log.txt"
sftp.get(filepath, localpath)

# Close
if sftp: sftp.close()
if transport: transport.close()
```

However when I run this program I get a file not found error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/Code/log.txt'

Clearly the file is here

```
po@raspberrypi:~/Code $ pwd
/home/pi/Code
po@raspberrypi:~/Code $ ls
a.out  log.txt  test.c
po@raspberrypi:~/Code $ _
```

[(terminal screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHksO.png)

But the program can't seem to find it.

I had thought that perhaps the connection had died. I tried a suggestion found here:
[Check if paramiko ssh connection is still alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288533/check-if-paramiko-ssh-connection-is-still-alive)

```
transport.send_ignore()
```

Did not yield an error.

I am new to Paramiko. Do I need to run something on the Pi in order for this to work? Is it not simply a wrapper for SFTP/SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your immediate problem is that you have the parameters of [`SFTPClient.get`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get) the other way around (you even have the variables named wrong, the `localpath` should obviously be `remotepath`). So Paramiko tries to create a local file with the path of your remote file. As `/home/pi/Code` does not exist on your *local* (target) machine, you get *local* `FileNotFoundError` error.
2. Once you correct this, you will have another problem. The `localpath` path argument of `SFTPClient.get` needs to be path to the file, not only path to the target directory. See [Python Paramiko, PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when get files from remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53760297/850848).

So like this:

```
localpath = "/log.txt"
remotepath = "/home/pi/Code/log.txt"
sftp.get(remotepath, localpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You messed up the order of the parameters. Or use '//' for the file path

Comment: Please expand your answer. What specifically is wrong?

Comment: @LyraOrwell, you are using the remote path as your local path. If you really want to save the file to `/` on your local machine, swap the values of `filepath` and `localpath`.